# Javascript inheritance (through Backbone source code), why Surrogate function in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Usual way to implement inheritance in javascript is something like:

```
function Person(name, surname) {
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
}

Person.prototype.whoAmI = function() {
  console.log("I'am " + this.name + " " + this.surname);
}

function Ninja() {
  Person.apply(this, arguments); // call to parent constructor
}

Ninja.prototype = new Person();
Ninja.prototype.constructor = Ninja;

var ninja = new Ninja("John", "Doe");
ninja.whoAmI();
```

From backbone what i can see is use of "Surrogate" function like: (very simplified example of what i can extract like example from Backbone source code)

```
function Person(name, surname) {
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
}

Person.prototype.whoAmI = function() {
  console.log("I'am " + this.name + " " + this.surname);
}

function Ninja() {
  Person.apply(this, arguments);
}

var Surrogate = function() { this.constructor = Ninja; }
Surrogate.prototype = Person.prototype;
Ninja.prototype = new Surrogate();

var ninja = new Ninja("John", "Doe");
ninja.whoAmI();
```

From what i can understand, these examples work exactly same so why need for Surrogate function.
I find one comment in the source about this:

> Set the prototype chain to inherit from `parent`, without calling
>   `parent`'s constructor function.

Why not calling parent constructor function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why not calling parent constructor function?

Because we want to constructor function to be only called when an instance is created. The `Ninja.prototype` however is not an instance of `Person`, it should not have `name` or `surname` properties - it should only inherit the `whoAmI` method. See also [What is the reason to use the 'new' keyword at Derived.prototype = new Base](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572) for details.

> Usual way to implement inheritance in javascript is something like

Only "something like". The correct way is not to call the parent constructor, but we don't need that `Surrogate` thingy for that. The standard is just to use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
Ninja.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Ninja.prototype.constructor = Ninja;
```

<sub>(for compatibility with ES3 environments just *shim* `Object.create` instead of littering your source code with `Surrogate` functions)</sub>